# apache htaccess in subdirectories with cpanel/whm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I'm using a cpanel/whm setup.

htaccess files work fine for the base directory (public_html) but anything below that (public_html/stuff/) isn't processed. I'm aware I need to set AllowOverride, but where exactly do I enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AllowOverride Directive is set in the apache global configuration file.  This file is managed by cPanel and it's important not to edit sections labeled not to edis as those edits will be lost.

The configuration file is located at: /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

You're looking for a section that looks like the following since the AllowOverride directive is only available inside a <directory> section of the configuration file.

```
<Directory "/">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After you ensure that this AllowOverride is enabled in the apache configuration you will need to let cPAnel know that you have updated the file by running the following command:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update
```

More about the AllowOverride Directive:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

cPanel Logs and Configuration Posters:

- http://go.cpanel.net/logposter
- http://go.cpanel.net/configposter